# BitmapText using fabricjs

Tags: fonts, html5-canvas, fabricjs, webfonts

I researched for fonts that used in HTML5 & CSS3. I know web-fonts (like ttf/otf, eot, woff,woff2) will support in Web pages. But, I need to use ***.fon** fonts (font that used in native application) in canvas.

I refered the [link](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/creating-custom-objects-fabric.js?langswitch=en) that bitmaptext can be used with extending fabric.image. But, i need to use bitmaptext like normal text object of fabricjs. eg. font-style, wrapping, line spacing, font change, etc.

Is it possible to do with **bitmaptext** or is there any other way to render text from ***.fon** files?

[.fon file converted to bitmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITDgw.png)

Comment: Can't you convert this .fon in a web compatible font? looks like the best solution.

Comment: Can. But, i want to change the character fontsize(width and height will not be proportionate) not like normal text fontsize. eg. if i use 6x9 font which character width is 6px and height is 9px, then my fontsize may be 12x9 or 6x18. thats not possible in normal web font.

Comment: So your best bet is to subclass iText instead of text, and override the rendering method, at that point you have an editable bitmap text

Comment: Currently, i created a character set with *.fon as image and extended the fabric.image class as reference from [link](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/creating-custom-objects-fabric.js?langswitch=en). 
is your opinion is to extend IText instead of Image?

Comment: What do you think to make a tutorial from this use case? I can add the tutorial to fabricjs.com an then post it here as a link, or copy the full code in the answer. I Think is nice use case for a subclass tutorial

Comment: of course fill color, stroke will not work. You will just get the wrapping, the bold, and underline probably. And realt time edit

Comment: I have to use only the .fon files; Not the web compatible font;
That is the reason to use BitmapText class which helps to render text from .fon file as an **image** actually.
But I am not able to use text / itext properties like wrapping, font style, etc as I am using the image(bitmapText class) instead of text.
What do you suggest??

Comment: sorry for delay to share [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/VijayaDinagar/orfn3qhm/) which i currently working with fabric subclass from Image. kindly check this and give me suggestion.

Comment: Can you provide me the .fon file converted to a bitmap?

Comment: Here is [.fon bitmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITDgw.png)

Comment: Hi @AndreaBogazzi, any suggestions?

Comment: I have been busy with fabricJs change, maybe today i can try it.

Comment: ok, is .fon bitmap file workable? any suggestions?

Comment: Hey i did something. i cannot go way deeper, you have to figure out additional extensions by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see a basic override of the Textbox class.

I added all the properties i needed to handle the basic functionality, i stubbed the measureChar function to return the fixed width of the bitmap font, 6px.

At initialize time i create a map that tells me the position of the most common chars in the bitmap font, and finally i wrote a simple render method that retrieve the part of the canvas it needs in order to draw that character.

You still need to figure out fontColor, fontSize, doubleWidth and doubleHeight, but should be straight forward now that you have this example

```js
(function() {
  fabric.BitmapText = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
    type: 'bitmapText',
    bitmap: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITDgw.png',
    readyToRender: false,
    charWidth: 6,
    charHeight: 9,
    fontSize: 9,

    charMap: ' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}'
      .split('').reduce(function(acc, char, index) {
        acc[char] = index + 31;
        return acc;
      }, {}),
    initialize: function(text, options) {
      this.callSuper('initialize', text, options);
      var image = fabric.document.createElement('img');
      image.onload = (function() {
        var canvas = fabric.document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        console.log(canvas.width)
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        this.bitmapResource = canvas;
        this.readyToRender = true;
        this.dirty = true;
        if (this.canvas) this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
      }).bind(this);
      image.src = this.bitmap;
    },

    // override: make it return a fixed box 6x9
    _measureChar: function(_char, charStyle, previousChar, prevCharStyle) {
      return { width: 6, kernedWidth: 6 };
    },

    _renderChar: function(method, ctx, lineIndex, charIndex, _char, left, top) {
      if (!this.readyToRender) return;
      var charMap = this.charMap, res = this.bitmapResource;
      _char.split('').forEach(function(singleChar) {
        ctx.drawImage(res, charMap[singleChar] * 6, 0, 5, 9, left, top - 6, 5, 9);
        ctx.translate(6, 0);
      });
    },
  });


  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  var text = new fabric.BitmapText('Hello i am a bitmap text');

  canvas.add(text);
  canvas.setActiveObject(text);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.1.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="350" height="400" />
```

Comment: Thanks @AndreaBogazzi, it works well in snippet. May i know which version of fabric.js you used with? currently i working with fabric 1.7.19

Comment: i used latest 2.1.0, that todays should become 2.2.0. You should move on the latest if you are on early project stage. This override will probably not work with 1.7 since measure char was different

Comment: thanks, @AndreaBogazzi. It's working fine. I am rendering with multiline text in bitmaptext. can I able to render the different line of text with different bitmap source?

Comment: in line "ctx.drawImage(res, charMap[singleChar] * 6, 0, 5, 9, left, top - 6, 5, 9); ". I like to know the purpose of top difference from 6.

Comment: the purpose of that difference is just to align text with cursor, is just a value find by trial and error.

Comment: Thanks @AndreaBogazzi